# Double border on Bootstrap accordion when collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, border, accordion

I have a page that displays information from a db in a while loop. Using Bootstrap table and a var $loopcounter that gives each line a separate id. When cliking on a line I am able to expand on the information for each row. This works perfect, thanks to SO and Google.

My problem now is that the table is displaying a double line for the hidden/collapsed row. I have tried several solutions like padding:0 !important, border-color: #FFF, border-color: none, nothing seems to work. Also tried colspan, but that only expands the double line further.

HTML:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Adr</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while ($row = $variable->fetch()) { $loopcounter++ ;?>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#row<?php echo $loopcounter; ?>" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['adr']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="row<?php echo $loopcounter; ?>"> 
          <table>
              <thead><tr><td>Some Header</td></tr></thead>
              <tbody><tr><td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td></tr></tbody>
           </table>
         </div> 
       </td>
     </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
    .hiddenRow {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-color: FFF;
}
```

IMAGE:
Notice the double border when row is collapsed

[image]

Comment: any fiddle demo available??

Comment: Sure; https://jsfiddle.net/thmcts1j/ Double line not present on the fiddle though.. Perhaps the while loop is causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had actually a pretty easy solution, just styled the hidden TD with border:none